# Рисование поверх картинки в Qt

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, qt4

Есть программа, которая открывает изображение:

```
pixmap = QPixmap("pic.jpg")
self.image = QLabel (self)
self.image.setPixmap(pixmap)
self.image.move(200,10)
self.image.setObjectName("image")
```

Далее, по клику мыши на это изображение получает координаты точки клика. Как сделать так чтобы в этих координатах программа ставила точку?
Пытался делать через функцию:

```
pen = QPen(Qt.black,10)
qp=QPainter(self.image)
qp.setPen(pen)
qp.drawPoint(x,y)
```

Ничего не приходит, ошибок не выдает, точек не рисует. Картинка и функция рисования в одном классе. Использую *python3.4*, *qt4*.

```
class MainGui(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_UI()

    def init_UI(self):
        self.pixmap = QPixmap("pic.jpg")
        self.image = QLabel (self)
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.image.move(200,10)
        self.image.setObjectName("image")
        self.image.mousePressEvent = self.get_pos

   def drawPoints(self, pos):
        pen = QPen(Qt.black,10)
        qp=QPainter(self.image)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.begin (self.image)
        qp.drawPoint(pos.x(),pos.y())
        self.image.update()

   def get_pos(self, event):
        X=event.pos().x()
        y=event.pos().y()
        self.drawPoints(event.pos())

if __name__ =='__main__':
     app = QApplication(sys.argv)
     ex = MainGui()
     ex.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Не писал на питоне, но экстраполируя свой опыт из C++, предположу что нужно попробовать `qp.begin(self.image); qp.drawPoint(x,y); qp.end();`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Проверьте координаты x и y, и размер изображения -- возможно выходит за границы картинки. Кроме того, попробуйте рисовать не на QLabel, а на его pixmap, т.к. я не думаю, что изменения останутся на виджете (вы ведь не в paintEvent'е рисуете).

Comment: Координаты точно правильные. В картинку попадают. Пытаюсь через пиксмап, тоже не выходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще важным моментом является то, какими свойствами должна обладать ваша точка.

Если просто отобразить и забыть, то можно рисовать прямо на `QPixmap`, если что-то более сложное, то нужно присмотреться к `QGraphicsView` и `QGraphicsItem`.

Например вот так:

```
from PyQt4 import Qt


class DrawableLabel(Qt.QLabel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DrawableLabel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def drawPoint(self, pos):
        qp = Qt.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self.pixmap())
        qp.setPen(Qt.Qt.red)
        qp.drawPoint(pos.x(), pos.y())

    def mousePressEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        event = args[0]
        self.drawPoint(event.pos())
        self.update()
        return Qt.QLabel.mousePressEvent(self, *args, **kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    label = DrawableLabel()
    pix = Qt.QPixmap("pix.jpg")
    label.setPixmap(pix)
    label.show()

    app.exec()
```

Ваш код не работает потому что у вас опечатка в названии метода `MousePressEvent`, а должно быть `mousePressEvent`. Т.е. у вас метод drawPoints вообще никогда не вызывается. И рисование нужно делать либо на `pixmap` объекта `QLabel`, либо переопределять метод `paintEvent`.

Вот исправленный код:

```
from PyQt4 import Qt
import sys

class MainGui(Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_UI()

    def init_UI(self):
        self.pixmap = Qt.QPixmap("pic.jpg")
        self.image = Qt.QLabel (self)
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.image.move(200, 10)
        self.image.setObjectName("image")
        self.image.mousePressEvent = self.get_pos

    def drawPoints(self, pos):
        print("Call draw points")
        pen = Qt.QPen(Qt.Qt.black, 10)
        qp = Qt.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self.image.pixmap())
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawPoint(pos.x(), pos.y())
        self.image.update()

    def get_pos(self, event):
        X = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y()
        self.drawPoints(event.pos())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainGui()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Попробовал по разному сделать по вашему примеру, эффект тот же. Только когда вписал pixmap() выдало ошибку "object is not callable". Да, точки можно просто отобразить и забыть потом, просто чтоб они остались на экране пока программа работает

Comment: Пробовали мой код запустить? Если у вас выдается ошибка для pixmap, значит вы где то его переопределили, так как pixmap метод в классе QLabel, который возвращает текущий QPixmap.

А какая версия PyQt4 у вас установлена? Под какой операционной системой запускаете?

Comment: Ваш код работает, но я не смог его экстраполировать на свой случай. Я написал более развернутый код в самом вопросе, пожалуйста, взгляните, может быть поймете что не так. Спасибо!

Comment: Добавил ваш исправленный код в ответ.

Comment: "mouse" было с маленькой буквы. Дело было в qp.begin(self.image.pixmap()) Спасибо! Теперь все работает